# google checkout in iphone native application?

Tags: iphone, ipad, google-checkout

i  am new to google checkout and also iphone sdk.Tutorials are saying that google checkout is for website integration.They have given lot of restriction,buttons etc.is it possible to intgrate google check out successfully in iphone native application?They give html source code also when we want to do buy now button.how can i integrate in iphone sdk?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that'll get your app rejected by Apple, as you can only purchase stuff through your application using their in-app purchase system.

Comment: how paypal has provided their source in their website for iphone for payment ? how it  was approved by apple?did know that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer following [link:](http://www.linkedin.com/answers/technology/wireless/TCH_WIR/598582-184940)
or

Yes there is. Technically.

Run it in a UIWebView would be the simplest way of doing it.

You could also make custom calls to the Google Checkout with [NSUrlConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)

Just make sure you do not interfere with the Apple approval guidelines. If you want to charge inapp purchases, you will have to use iTunes. Apple will not let go of their 30% ;]